# SAS exports values of 0 as period in excel

Tags: sas

I have a major issue. I am running a report in SAS that saves the results in an excel output. Problem is that whenever the value is 0 sas fills the column as a period (.)

Is there any way to prevent this? I want SAS to populate the value 0 not .

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without your code it is difficult to determine the problem. If you are using Proc Report or Proc Print try:

```
Options Missing=0;
```

Comment: And if you prefer to have excel leave the cell blank then use `option missing=' ';`.  After you have performed the export you may also want to reset it back to a period, just use `option missing='.';`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually alter the data set, use the below and read the SAS documentation at http://support.sas.com/kb/24/693.html

```
/* Example 1 - Convert all numeric missing values to zero.           */
/*                                                                   */
/* Use the ARRAY statement with the automatic _NUMERIC_ variable to  */
/* process all the numeric variables from the input data set.  Use   */
/* the DIM function to set the upper bound of an iterative DO to the */
/* number of elements in the array.                                  */
/*                                                                   */
/* NOTE: The MISSING function can be used as well to test for        */
/*       character or numeric missing values.  If you have           */
/*       mixed data types and want to use arrays, you'll need one    */
/*       array for the character variables, and another array for    */
/*       numeric variables.                                          */
```

> ```
> data nomiss(drop=i);                                                    
> set ***YOUR DATA SET HERE***;                                                            
> array testmiss(*) _numeric_;                                            
> do i = 1 to dim(testmiss);                                              
> if testmiss(i)=. then testmiss(i)=0;                                    
> end; 
> run;
> ```

CarolinaJay's answer is better if the issue is only in the export as it doesn't alter any values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use proc stdize.

```
Proc stdize data=base_data out=output_data reponly missing=0;run;
```